# How to safely HTML encode content which may already be HTML encoded?

Tags: c#, html-encode

I need to HTML encode some text which may or may not already be HTML encoded (perhaps only partially). Is the following safe? Are there any characters/encodings that could cause unexpected behaviour?

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text))
```

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I might be afraid of is that the text might have been encoded differently? Unless you are the only person encoding the text, using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, then I guess it's fine.

Comment: the encoding is coming from TinyMCE

Comment: which means it could be user entered (as &amp; for example) or TinyMCE could have encoded it. Basically, I can't trust it, but it should be valid. If the user has entered invalid encoding then thats their problem if it displays funny, not worried about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic "`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text))`" is safe. There is a standard for HTML characters encoding. [Take a look.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any way calling `Decode` could mess something up, i didnt think so but i thought id check with people first

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality. But I would use:

```
 return 
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text)!=text ? text : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
```